# How to add a nil entry in Go protobuf slice field with protoreflect?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, protoreflect

My generated protobuf Go struct looks like:

```
type ProtoStruct {
   A []*SomeStruct
}
```

I am now trying to append a `nil` entry to that slice with `protoreflect`.

I tried:

```
var v protoreflect.Value // somehow get this value from previous steps
v.List().Append(protoreflect.ValueOf(nil))
```

And it panics with:

> type mismatch: cannot convert nil to message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to `List().Append()` is supposed to be a `protoreflect.Value` that carries appropriate type information.

To append a **typed** protobuf `nil` item, you can use [`protoreflect.ValueOf`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoreflect#ValueOf) in this way:

```
var a *pb.SomeStruct
v.List().Append(protoreflect.ValueOf(a.ProtoReflect()))
```

Note that this will ***not cause a panic*** for nil pointer dereference. The `ProtoReflect()` method call deals with the receiver being `nil`; it will return an appropriately initialized `protoreflect.Message` wrapping a `nil` value, which you can then successfully pass into `ValueOf`.